# iOS UI Testing willDisplayCell is not working properly

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I just started studying for UI Testing in iOS. Currently, my app is just like facebook (show newfeed). When user scroll down and if it is last row, I need to request new data and I do like this.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.tblSortingInListingVC)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (tableView == self.tblListing || tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSInteger lastRow = 0;
        if (tableView == self.tblListing) lastRow =  self.viewData.count - 1;
        else lastRow =  self.searchViewData.count - 1;

        if ([indexPath row] == lastRow)
        {
            if(tableView == self.tblListing || tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
            {
                [self loadMoreToListingView]; //Method to request to server to get more data
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Problem is that **if ([indexPath row] == lastRow)**  is always true and it keep on requesting if I do UI testing like this (either typing or scrolling tables). How shall I do so that it won't request again and again?

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.tables.staticTexts[@"Apr 04 16:28"] tap];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a flag (called `isReload`) to manage your request again & again.
So How do you manage this flag ?. It's very simple in your ViewController
define a variable `isReload` and set initial value of it `YES`. now check `isReload` flag to call web service in `loadMoreToListingView` method that you implemented like.

```
-(void)loadMoreToListingView {

    if (isReload) {
        // here call your web -service ...
    }
}
```

Now In Response of web-service, you need to check is search list & update `isReload` flag as I'm doing below.

```
NSArray *searchData = response[@"searchData"];
// So when ever no data comes from server then this flag will be flase.
// So isReload will not call webservice Again&again
isReload = gps_details.count > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I don't do UI Testing, everything is working properly. It doesn't call again and again.